# How to add attributes to properties of a class generated (web service proxy)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, proxy-classes, dataform

I have a Silverlight 3 application which gets data from a web service. When I add a reference to my web service, all the classes used by the web service are defined in a proxy class. So far, so good... Now, I would like to use the DataForm offered in Silverlight 3. To use that component, I must add metadata to my class (e.g. see code below).

```
public class Movie : IEditableObject
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="The Movie Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

My question is, considering the class Movie is defined in the proxy class generated by .NET, how do I add the attributes/metadeta to the properties of the Movie class without modifying the class generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In short; you don't. Don't edit the generated code, since your changes will be lost the next time it is generated.

Instead, create your own `Movie` class inside your application and create methods that translates the generated `Movie` proxy class to your internal `Movie` class (and back), and then make your internal class have the desired behavior. I usually wrap this together at a low level, so that most of my code never see the generated proxy classes.

Answer (score 1):

If converting your web service to use .NET RIA Services is a possibility you can use this technique to apply attributes to properties without using a wrapper class:

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/21/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-7-services-based-data-store.aspx

With RIA Services you apply the attributes on the server side - the code generator is intelligent enough to pick them up and apply them on the client side as well when it generates code.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you really need to add something to the generated class, you can still use the partial class to achieve without modifying anything within the generated class.

Comment: To be clear: you can add members, but you can't add metadata to *existing* members.

Comment: @Marc, I am not sure if this is a way, http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/01/06/ASPNETDynamicDataTutorialBuddyMetadataProviderCustomMetadataProviders.aspx